How to fill Powerpoint table from Excel data
I have an excel data that contains range from A40 to G1330, but the actual range is from A40 to G63 because the remaining range has formula but the cell is empty "I applied the formula IFERROR make the cell empty"
also I have an exsist powerpoint file and slide number 3 contains of a table with name "Table 1"
what I want is to fill the table which is in the powerpoint file from the excel range from range D40 to E63
I have tried the following code
Dim Name_Attendees_lastVal As Range
Dim sht As Worksheet 
Dim pptapp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim presentation As PowerPoint.presentation
Dim ppslide As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim slidetitle As String
Dim pptfile As String
Dim slideCtr As Integer
Set sht = Sheets("Reports")
Set Name_Attendees_lastVal = sht.Columns(5).Find("*", sht.Cells(1, 2), xlValues, xlPart, xlByColumns,xlPrevious)
sht.Range("D40", Name_Attendees_lastVal).Resize(, 2).Select
pptfile = "C:\Users\habinalshaikh\Desktop\Training\presentation maker\Course Report.pptx" 
Set pptapp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
pptapp.Visible = True 
pptapp.Presentations.Open (pptfile)
 for i = 40 to Set Name_Attendees_lastVal = sht.Columns(5).Find("*", sht.Cells(1, 2), xlValues, xlPart, xlByColumns, xlPrevious).count  ' this code is to count the number of rows, but it doesn't work
 pptapp.ActivePresentation.Slides(3).Shapes("Table 1").TextFrame.TextRange.Characters.Text = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Reports").Range("D"&i)   ' this code is to fill the table which is in the PowerPoint file with the names in the excel sheet
next
 for y = 40 to Set Name_Attendees_lastVal = sht.Columns(5).Find("*", sht.Cells(1, 2), xlValues, xlPart, xlByColumns, xlPrevious).count  ' this code is to count the number of rows, but it doesn't work
  pptapp.ActivePresentation.Slides(3).Shapes("Table 1").TextFrame.TextRange.Characters.Text = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Reports").Range("E"&i)' this code is to fill the table which is in the PowerPoint file with the Attending status in the excel sheet
next


How many columns are in Table 1? Do you want to insert the contents of cells D40 and E40 into the same row of Table 1?

There are 2 columns in Table 1. And I want to insert from D40 to the last row contains value “not empty” to Table 1. And same with E40

There are some syntax error in below code.
' this code is to count the number of rows, but it doesn't work
 for i = 40 to Set Name_Attendees_lastVal = sht.Columns(5).Find("*", sht.Cells(1, 2), xlValues, xlPart, xlByColumns, xlPrevious).count  


Set can't be used in For clause
The Find method returns either Nothing or a Range object; if it returns a Range object, the Row property is used to obtain the row number.
The second argument (After) of Find must be within the searched range (Columns(5)); otherwise, a runtime error 13 will occur.

Microsoft documentation:

Range.Find method (Excel)


Option Explicit
Sub Excel2PPTTable()
    Dim Name_Attendees_lastVal As Range
    Dim oSht As Worksheet
    Dim pptApp As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim pptPres As PowerPoint.presentation
    Dim pptSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
    Dim pptTab As PowerPoint.Table
    Dim pptfile As String
    Dim iR As Long, i As Long
    Const START_ROW = 2 ' change to 1 if there isn't a header row in Table1
    Set oSht = Sheets("Reports")
    pptfile = "C:\Users\habinalshaikh\Desktop\Training\presentation maker\Course Report.pptx"
    Set pptApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    pptApp.Visible = True
    Set pptPres = pptApp.Presentations.Open(pptfile)
    Set pptTab = pptPres.Slides(3).Shapes("Table 1").Table
    If pptTab Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Can't find table on the third slide."
    Else
        With oSht.Columns(4)
            Set Name_Attendees_lastVal = .Find("*", .Cells(1), xlValues, xlPart, xlByRows, xlPrevious)
        End With
        iR = START_ROW - 1
        For i = 40 To Name_Attendees_lastVal.Row
            iR = iR + 1
            pptTab.Cell(iR, 1).Shape.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = oSht.Range("D" & i) ' the names in the excel sheet
            pptTab.Cell(iR, 2).Shape.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = oSht.Range("E" & i) ' the Attending status in the excel sheet
        Next
    End If
    '    pptPres.Save ' save file
    '    pptPres.Close ' close file
    '    pptApp.Quit    ' close ppt app.
End Sub


